# how to get the time from timestamp without time zone data type of parameter in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

HI i have a 2 parameters which is timestamp without time zone data type, i am calculating the these 2 parameter clock_out_time  and clock_in_time

here is my function

```
(select EXTRACT ( hour from (select sum( att.clock_out_time - att.clock_in_time) 
            from public."VOfficeApp_employee_attendence" att
            where att.user_id = 2017
            and att.company_id =391 
            and date_part('month', date) = 4)))
```

OUTPUT:
"24"
WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR:
"24:38:30.084"

Actually i have to convert this days to  time how can i convert

```
29 days 24:38:30.084
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of subtracting a timestamp from a timestamp is an `interval`. You can format the result using [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

```
select to_char(sum(att.clock_out_time - att.clock_in_time), 'hh24:mi:ss.ff3') 
from public."VOfficeApp_employee_attendence" att
where att.user_id = 2017
  and att.company_id =391 
  and date_part('month', date) = 4)
```

---

Note that your outer SELECT wasn't necessary:

```
select extract(hour from sum(att.clock_out_time - att.clock_in_time)) 
from public."VOfficeApp_employee_attendence" att
where att.user_id = 2017
  and att.company_id =391 
  and date_part('month', date) = 4)
```